# How to prepend a string or integer to a variadic printf function?

Tags: c, variadic-functions

I have a debug function that takes a format and variable number of additional arguments (just like `printf()`), converts them to a formatted string stored in a buffer `buf`, and sends that buffer to a secondary function that actually prints it:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdarg.h>

    void debug_printf(const char *fmt, ...)
    {
        char buf[100];
        va_list va;

        va_start(va, fmt);

        /* Format the string and store it in buf */
        vsnprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), fmt, va);

        /* Actually print the buf. */
        actual_print(buf);

        va_end(va);
    }
```

How can I modify this function to prepend a string to the resulting output?  For example, a header like `DBG:` so that if I called `debug_printf("test1")` the result would print `DBG: test1`.

Alternatively, how can I modify this function take a variable integer (the return value of a function) and somehow prepend that as a string to the resulting output?  For example, if I had a function `rng()` that returned a random integer, I might call `debug_printf("test2")` and the result would print something like `3572 test2`, assuming `rng()` returned integer value `3572`.

For both cases, ideally the solution will modify the body of `debug_printf()` rather than wrap it in another function and/or a preprocessor macro.

**EDIT**: It appears I forgot an important point.  For performance reasons, I would greatly prefer to only call `actual_printf()` **once** within `debug_printf()`.  Otherwise yes, it would be a fairly easy solution to call it twice:  Once with the header and again with the actual formatted string.  Sorry about that!

Comment: Does your question really boil down to "how do I concatenate two strings"?

Comment: For starters, you can add a `printf("DBG: ");` just about anywhere in the first half.

Comment: Also, use caution with `printf(buf)`. If `buf` happens to contain format specifiers, you will invoke UB (and probably crash). Instead, use `printf("%s", buf)`.

Comment: Please note that nowhere in this question do I actually call `printf`.  :)

Comment: why not prepending an `actual_print("DEBUG: ");` line? or put that before `buf` buffer?

Comment: @AndrewCottrell Indeed. I offered it as a warning (to other readers as well) since it is not clear from your code what `actual_print()` does and because it's a common mistake even by experienced C programmers.

Comment: Excellent points all.  Thanks for the quick feedback!  I've updated the question to spell out that I only want to call `actual_printf()` once within the function.

Comment: " For performance reasons, I would greatly prefer to only call actual_printf() once within debug_printf()" is likely a minor performance concern.  `vsnprintf()` is a sink-hole of clock cycles.

Comment: @chux - Hehe.  I'm doing some crazynuts stuff inside of actual_printf().  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Print into buf whatever you want to prepend and that's it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

void debug_printf(const char *fmt, ...)
{
    char buf[100];
    va_list va;

    va_start(va, fmt);

    int n = snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "DBG: ");

    /* Format the string and store it in buf */
    vsnprintf(buf + n, sizeof(buf) - n, fmt, va);

    /* Actually print the buf. */
    actual_print(buf);

    va_end(va);
}
```

There's no need to use a fixed size.  The manpage has an example to calculate the right size for the buffer to allocate with malloc():

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html

Comment: `snprintf` returns the number of characters read. Can come in handy if your string isn't known because it's a number printed as string

Comment: Yup, that'll work.  Thanks for the answer!  I was so hung up on the variadic nonsense that it didn't occur to me to modify the buffer directly separate from all that.

Comment: Also, there is absolutely a need to use a fixed size:  I'm an embedded developer.  There is no malloc() in my world.  :)

Comment: Suggest `puts(buf);` --> `fputs(buf, stdout);`  `puts(buf);` append a `'\n'` on printing.

Comment: Also, I'm not calling `puts` or `fputs`.  It has to go to custom function `actual_print`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of finding a complicated way to insert another parameter in the variadic list, you can just add a simple printf in the beginning of your code:
`printf("%d ",rng());`

Comment: Excellent point.  I am going to update my question to clarify.